# How can I combine methods from the EC2 resource and client API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm trying to take in input for stopping and starting instances, but if I use client, it comes up with the error:

> 'EC2' has no attribute 'instance'

and if I use resource, it says

> 'ec2.Serviceresource' has no attribute 'Instance'

Is it possible to use both?

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import boto3
import botocore
import sys

print('Enter Instance id: ')
instanceIdIn=input()

ec2=boto3.resource('ec2')

ec2.Instance(instanceIdIn).stop()
stopwait=ec2.get_waiter('instance_stopped')
try:
    stopwait.wait(instanceIdIn)
    print('Instance Stopped. Starting Instance again.')
except botocore.exceptions.waitError as wex:
    logger.error('instance not stopped')
    
ec2.Instance(instanceIdIn).start()
try:
    logger.info('waiting for running state...')
    print('Instance Running.')
except botocore.exceptions.waitError as wex2:
    logger.error('instance has not been stopped')
```

Comment: Declaration of ec2 seems to be missing ?’ ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=REGION_NAME)’

Comment: That's optional  @BaluVyamajala, it will just take the default region if it isn't explicitly mentioned.

Comment: true. I didn't see the whole declaration line. still feeling sleepy i guess. thx.

Answer (score 0):

In boto3 there's two kinds of APIs for most service - a **resource**-based API, which is supposed to be an abstraction of the lower level API calls that the **client** API provides.

You can't directly mix and match calls to these. Instead you should create a separate instance for each of those like this:

```py
import boto3

ec2_resource = boto3.resource("ec2")
ec2_client = boto3.client("ec2")

# Now you can call the client methods on the client
# and resource classes from the resource:

my_instance = ec2_resource.Instance("instance-id")

my_waiter = ec2_client.get_waiter("instance_stopped")
```